# simple and best way of list manipulation in python

Tags: python

How to retrieve result from data below:

```
data = ['    MY_YEAR_4 = 1990.000']

result = [i.split('=')[1] for i in data]
```

The result should be in float

```
result = 1990.00
```

Best way of getting the result is requested.

Comment: 'Give me the codez` style of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily make use of [`str.rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
>>> data = ['    MY_YEAR_4 = 1990.000']
>>> float(data[0].rsplit('= ', 1)[1])
1990.0
```

If `data` has multiple items, use a loop:

```
results = [float(item.rsplit('= ', 1)[1]) for item in data]
```

Comment: In case the item on LHS also contains `=`'s then we can pass `maxsplit=1` to `rsplit` to reduce the number of splits. +1

Comment: Indeed, added. Or just grab the last index.

Comment: ...or use __rpartition('= ')[-1]__, which will be the most efficient way

Comment: @viena because `data` is a list here. If there are multiple values in this list, use a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner:

```
[float(re.search('[\d\.]+$', d).group(0)) for d in data]
```